# I am getting an error while scraping title urls using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code to scrape title URLs but I'm getting an error while extracting title urls so could you please guide me.
here is my code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# import pandas as pd
# import pandas as pd
import csv


def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        # 1. html , 2. parser
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        titles_link = soup.find_all('a', class_="body_link_11")
    except:
        titles_link = []
    # urls = [item.get('href') for item in titles_link]
    print(titles_link)


def main():
    mainurl = "http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/search/collection/p4013coll8/" \
              "searchterm/1/field/all/mode/all/conn/and/order/nosort/page/1"
    get_index_data(get_page(mainurl))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What is your error? Please provide the full stack trace. You should also check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the links try this:

```
def get_page(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if not response.ok:
        print('server responded:', response.status_code)
    else:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser') # 1. html , 2. parser
    return soup

def get_index_data(soup):
    try:
        titles_link = soup.find_all('a',class_="body_link_11")
    except:
        titles_link = []
    else:
        titles_link_output = []
        for link in titles_link:
            try:
                item_id = link.attrs.get('item_id', None) # All titles with valid links will have an item_id
                if item_id:
                    titles_link_output.append("{}{}".format("http://cgsc.cdmhost.com",link.attrs.get('href', None)))
            except:
                continue
        print(titles_link_output)

def main():
    mainurl = "http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/search/collection/p4013coll8/searchterm/1/field/all/mode/all/conn/and/order/nosort/page/1"
    get_index_data(get_page(mainurl))

main()
```

Output:

```
['http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/2653/rec/1', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/2385/rec/2', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3309/rec/3', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/2425/rec/4', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/150/rec/5', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/compoundobject/collection/p4013coll8/id/2501/rec/6', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/compoundobject/collection/p4013coll8/id/2495/rec/7', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3672/rec/8', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3407/rec/9', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/4393/rec/10', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3445/rec/11', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3668/rec/12', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3703/rec/13', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/2952/rec/14', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/2898/rec/15', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3502/rec/16', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3553/rec/17', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/4052/rec/18', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3440/rec/19', 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/singleitem/collection/p4013coll8/id/3583/rec/20']
```

Comment: thank you sir! Could you please add main part of the website with href? this is the main part 'http://cgsc.cdmhost.com'

Comment: I don`t understand what you mean by adding the "main" part?

Comment: This is the main part http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/ and this is other part that we are scraping cdm/search/collection/p4013coll8/searchterm/1/field/all/mode/all/conn/and/order/nosort/page/1   just conncate them like complete url     eg:http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/search/collection/p4013coll8/searchterm/1/field/all/mode/all/conn/and/order/nosort/page/1